# Trigger existing fancybox with a href

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

So I'm really stuck at this point.
In my case I've got an gallery with pictures.

On the main image is a a href to  trigger the fancybox with his child-pictures.
This works, np.

Now I've got a footer with an a href and text.. 
When I click this link it has to open the Fancybox from the main-image with the child-pictures.

Yes this is possible with a simple a href.. yes you'll get a duplicate picture in your gallery. I don't need redundancy.

Help me and I'll promise to help in our war against Apple.

Code snippet:

```
echo '<ul style="padding:0;">';
       $query = "  SELECT 
            * 
           FROM 
            fotos AS f
           WHERE f.id = '29'
           ";

       #echo $query;
       $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
       $count = 0;   
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
       { $count++;
        echo '<div style="float:left;margin-top:5px;"><a style="text-decoration:none;color:black;" rel="gal_'.$row['id'].'"  href="'.$row['fotos'].'"
        title="<b>Navigeren met de pijltoetsen door het album</b>">
        <img src="'.$row{"fotos"}.'" border="0" />   

        </a>';
        if($count == 1)
        </div></div>';

        $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fotos WHERE type ='".$row['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());   
        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
        {
         echo '<a rel="gal_'.$row2{"type"}.'" href="'.str_replace('....', '..', $row2{"fotos"}).'" title="'.$row2{"omschrijving"}.'" style="display:none"></a>';
        }
       }

 echo '</ul>';
```

So this is my gallery.

Now i got an a href.. with the link below from here I want to trigger the fancybox above.

```
echo '<div id="foto_footer"> <a style="color:white;text-decoration:none;" title="<b>Navigeren met de pijltoetsen door het album</b>" id="openalbum" >Bekijk de diashow</a>
```

Comment: Which war? Have I missed something?

Comment: Samsung developers came to Stackoverflow :)

Comment: its not easy to understand what you need, can you post code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger clicking on other link, e.g,

```
$("#second_link").click(function() {
    $(#first_link").trigger("click");
});
```

Or you can create array of items un use it multiple times -

```
var items = [
    '1.jpg',
    '1.jpg',
    {
        'href'  : '3.jpg',
        'title' : 'Lorem ipsum'
    }
];

var opts = {
    'padding'   : 0,
    'type'      : 'image'
};

$(".open_manually").click(function() {
    $.fancybox(items, opts);
});
```